@Meadiapipe hands detection: sometimes I get fetch error
in general, hand detection works well, but lately I've been noticing this error periodically
      Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at ra.i (hands.js:78:225)
    at ua (hands.js:14:299)
    at va.next (hands.js:15:91)
    at hands.js:15:484
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at wa (hands.js:15:377)
    at E (hands.js:16:22)
    at hd (hands.js:78:152)
    at hands.js:70:1
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)

I understand that the reason is in the library, but can the service really work so unstable and how can I possibly have someone come across it and how did you solve it
